# ListView OnItemClickListener won't Work with Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView which I am using with a Custom Adapter and the OnItemClickListener Method Won't Work.

I tried searching on StackOverFlow but none of the answers seem to work.

Here is my code:

**row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="150sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {
    private ArrayList<DataItem> objects;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DataItem>     objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }


        DataItem i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {
            TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView recordView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.record);

            if (nameView != null){
                nameView.setText(i.getname());
                nameView.setTextSize(18);
                nameView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if (recordView != null){
                recordView.setText(i.getrecord());
                recordView.setTextSize(18);
                recordView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

DataItem:

```
public class DataItem {
    private String name;
    private String record;

    public DataItem() {

    }

    public DataItem(String n, String r) {
        this.name = n;
        this.record = r;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getrecord() {
        return record;
    }

    public void setrecord(String record) {
        this.record = record;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DataItem obj1 = new DataItem("Example 1", "$12");
        DataItem obj2 = new DataItem("Example 2", "$23");
        data.add(obj1);
        data.add(obj2);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.i("App Info: ", "Clicked!");

            }
        });
```

Basically, the problem here is that I am not able to make my onItemClickListener work; When I click an item in the listView, nothing happens. Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
KPS

Comment: Maybe you are new to Android, but noone using ListView for a long time, because it's too rough and outdated. Look at the RecyclerView (https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), it's better, modern and more flexible.

Comment: It's working ....i have tested your code..n i have put toast on listview onItemClick..and toast is appear when i click on listview item...whatever the issue is i m still posting your code as answer.

Comment: Thanks VortexHeatKiller for the idea. I actually didn't know about RecyclerViews because the course I took on Udemy never covered them. Thanks!

Comment: Try Removing `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from your row.xml's Linear Layout

Comment: That still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<DataItem> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        DataItem obj1 = new DataItem("Example 1", "$12");
        DataItem obj2 = new DataItem("Example 2", "$23");
        data.add(obj1);
        data.add(obj2);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.i("App Info: ", "Clicked!");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked"+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Remaining code is same as you code..Try this..because it is working for me

Comment: Let me attach screenshot

Comment: Do you think it could be an issue with the specific project that I am working in?

Comment: May be...because i have copied your code and its working..i have not changed anything in your code...

Comment: So I got the onItemClickListener to Work. But I have one more issue. I have a scroll view in which I have many listViews like these. The only problem is, the items in the ScrollView are getting cut off at the bottom. I don't want to post a video/screenshot on stackOverFlow but would be happy to PM anyone if they were interested in helping me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this screenshot,

[image]

You are printing a log onItemClick ,, so check you log if it is printing a log on List item Click or not.

Comment: Instead of posting another answer its better to edit your first answer !

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. It was just a layout issue. Thanks for your support!